# How to pass multiple files as a input to an api using Rest Assured

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest-assured, rest

In this method below I was making an API call to a locally running API that accepts only one file as a request, but is there any possible way to make an API call that accepts multiple files as request using Rest Assured dynamically at run time based on requests for that API? like how to add multiple files as an API request in Rest Assured at run time dynamically?

```
    public String restTest() {
        String resp = RestAssured.given().multiPart("file", new File("C:/Local/file/path/LocalFiles/file.txt")).when().post("http://localhost:4444/local/upload").then().assertThat().statusCode(200).and().extract().body().asString();

    return resp.toString();
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

        Response response;
        RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given().header("content-type", "multipart/form-data");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            request.multiPart("file", new File("D:/testtemplates98_" + i + "Data.xlsx"));// File parameters will be
                                                                                            // dynamic
        }
        response = request.post(new URL("https://jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/"));
        System.out.println(response.getBody().asString());
}
```

Comment: It is working perfectly . Thank you so much for providing logic

Answer (score 0):

rest assured uses a builder pattern so you can just stack the files like

```
given().
         multiPart("file1", new File("/home/johan/some_large_file.bin")).
         multiPart("file2", new File("/home/johan/some_other_large_file.bin")).
         multiPart("file3", "file_name.bin", inputStream).
         formParam("name", "value").
expect().
         body("fileUploadResult", is("OK")).
when().
         post("/advancedFileUpload");
```

and so you can send multiple files.

Comment: thanks for quick replay @[https://stackoverflow.com/users/5168458/tobsch] , like how can i do the same dynamically?

Comment: define a variable for given() e.g. and add dynamically the multiParts

Answer (score 0):

```
File files[] = getFileList();
RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given().contentType(ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.toString()).request();
for (File file: files) {
  request.multiPart("files", new File(file.getAbsolutePath()));
}
request.post().then().statusCode(200);
```