# Uploading Mutliple file using REST-assured

Tags: java, dsl, rest-assured, rest

I need to upload multiple files using [REST-assured](http://rest-assured.io), a Java DSL for easy testing of REST services. I succeeded to upload a single file. But I am not able to upload mutliple files. Can someone help me to upload multiple files in one request?

**Example of a single file upload:**

```java
RestAssured.given().auth().oauth2(acessToken)
  .multiPart("file",new File("temp.pdf"),"application/pdf")
  .when().post("https://www.example.com").then().log().all();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass multiple files as a input to an api using Rest Assured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62995600/how-to-pass-multiple-files-as-a-input-to-an-api-using-rest-assured)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage)

> It's also possible to supply multiple "multi-parts" entities in the same request

by chaining several multiPart() method calls in a row:

```java
RestAssured.given().auth().oauth2(acessToken)
  .multiPart("file",new File("temp.pdf"),"application/pdf")
  .multiPart("file",new File("readme.txt"),"text/plain")
  .when().post("https://www.example.com").then().log().all();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply  i followed the below URL it helpmed me to upload the n numbet of files

Answer (score 0):

AS per the below link  [How to pass multiple files as a input to an api using Rest Assured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62995600/how-to-pass-multiple-files-as-a-input-to-an-api-using-rest-assured) we are able to upload multiple file successfully
[How to pass multiple files as a input to an api using Rest Assured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62995600/how-to-pass-multiple-files-as-a-input-to-an-api-using-rest-assured)

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

```
    Response response;
    RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given().header("content-type", "multipart/form-data");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        request.multiPart("file", new File("D:/testtemplates98_" + i + "Data.xlsx"));// File parameters will be
                                                                                        // dynamic
    }
    response = request.post(new URL("https://jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/"));
    System.out.println(response.getBody().asString());
```

}